# Unmanaged switches keep breaking every month

Tags: networking, router, switch

I do have a **massive problem with unmanaged switches that just stop working out of the blue**. I'm on my 4th switch now (since june) and that one failed yesterday too.

Here's **my home network setup:**

- All in one router/switch/modem by Telekom (Speedport Smart 4)
- An unmanaged switch directly behind it (this is the one that keeps breaking)
- All my other devices are either connected through the unmanaged switch or directly to the speedport using wifi.
- Everything is wired up using cat6 ethernet cables

The **models of switches** I've tried so far (all broken now) are:

- D-Link DGS-108 8-Port Layer2 Gigabit Switch (tried two of those)
- Cisco Business CBS110-8T-D Unmanaged Switch
- TP-Link TL-SG108 V3 8-Ports Gigabit Network Switch

So **here's what happens**:

1. I buy a switch, it works just fine
2. After 3 to 6 weeks, I notice that some of my devices don't have a working internet connection anymore
3. I open up the management interface of my router. I still see all my devices connected through wifi, but all the devices connected to my switch no longer show up.
4. When I try to ping those devices, the ping fails (using the static IP adresses)
5. As soon as I connect any devices to the built-in switch on my router, they show up in the router management interface again and work just fine.
6. I buy a new switch on amazon
7. I install the new switch, connect my devices to it (same setup I described above) and everything instantly works again

I've gone through this process 4 times now, and I haven't been able to figure out what's going on. The switch does not seem broken

- It doesn't smell burned or fume
- All the LEDs are still working fine
- Looking at the hardware itself, it doesn't seem like anything is wrong with the switch at all.

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

- I suspected electromagnetic interference, but I've been moving the switches around and the problem still occurs (No other device in my entire network is acting weird at all)
- I tried to connect two devices to the switch, while the router was disconnected, but they still couldn't talk to each other using static IP addresses
- Temperature can't be the problem either, the switches even break when not enclosed in anything and the ambient temp doesn't exceed 22 celsius. The switch is also not standing in sunlight or anything like this.
- I like in Germany with a pretty stable power grid, so I don't think instable power supply could be the problem either.

**My suspicion is:**

- Something the router does, is causing the switch to fail. These problems started happening after I got a new router this summer.

**Is there anybody here who has an idea of what might be going on?** I feel like I'm going crazy with this and I can't keep buying new switches until I die.

edit: More weirdness - after trying to debug the switch on friday it started working again. I basically just had it disconnected for a few hours, plugged it into another of the LAN ports in the router and suddenly everything worked just fine again. When I woke up today everything was broken again and the situation was just like before…

Comment: electromagnetic interference wouldn’t cause the switches to permanently fail. electromagnetic interference would cause interment signal loss, connectivity issues perhaps, that were sporadic.  What you describe is out right complete hardware failures

Comment: This is a long shot, but have you tested with different ethernet cables or with different ports on the switch(es)? Is it possible to update the firmware on the router or perhaps to test with another router? I.m.o. It is not normal for these consumer/small business switches to fail so quickly, although you might just have had bad luck.

Comment: And one other thought: have you checked for (temporary) loops in your network, which would cause an unmanaged switch to stop forwarding data?

Comment: You have of course tried to unplug the switch from everything, wait for some time, then replug it and see if it still works? What happened? Is it still broken (which would mean "hardware damaged")? (And in the last year, four USB audio headsets died on me, so maybe it's just bad quality for products made in China ...)

Comment: "These problems started happening after I got a new router this summer." Sounds like you found the problem?

Comment: It could be an interference between the power supplies: every power supply causes some amount of "dirty electricity" (spikes, waves etc) when converting AC to DC. The switch might not be able to handle this. If you can, change the power supply or put router and switch on two different circuits, or at least plug them in as far away one from the other as possible.

Comment: Second thought: have you tried changing the LAN cables between Router and Switch? a damaged cable could be potentially devastating. Third thought: it could have to do with how your equipent is grounded [see this](https://www.cablinginstall.com/cable/article/16465312/ground-potentials-and-damage-to-lan-equipment)

Comment: If everything started when you got a new router, have you tried to replace the router again (with a different model this time)?

Comment: Seems like this post and bounty were abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was ultimately to just buy a managed switch instead. This works just fine and has caused zero issues so far. I still have no idea what caused these issues to begin with.